# Have error: "Failed to send email: no recipient"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sendmail

I'm getting the error when I run the code below:

Failed to send email: no recipient

This is being run off or a google spreadsheet. I'm assuming that it's going to look for an email address in the email address column and after it reads the last one, it goes for the next blank cell and doesn't see anything, then giving an error.

If this is the case, how can I get it to stop looking for email addresses when it goes to the last one in a column?

```
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('mail');
  
  let lr = sheet.getLastRow();

     let adress = sheet.getRange(lr,1).getValue();
     let name = sheet.getRange(lr,2).getValue();
     let chpri = sheet.getRange(lr,3).getValue();
     let chteh = sheet.getRange(lr,4).getValue();
     let chch = sheet.getRange(lr,5).getValue();  
     let chzsis = sheet.getRange(lr,6).getValue();
     let chho = sheet.getRange(lr,7).getValue();

  sender_mail(adress, name, chpri, chteh, chch, chzsis, chho);
}
```

and

````
  
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: adress, 
     subject: "Результат по опросу на профориентацию для " + name, 
     htmlBody:  
     "Здравствуйте предлагаем вам результат опроса на профориентацию" + "<br><br>" +
       "Человек-природа: " + chpri + "<br>" +
       "Человек-техника: " + chteh + "<br>" +
       "Человек-человек: " + chch + "<br>" +
       "Человек-знаковая система:  " + chzsis + "<br>" +
       "Человек-художественный образ: " + chho + "<br>" +

       "- «Человек-Природа» - все профессии, связанные с растениеводством,животноводством, лесным хозяйством, с охраной окружающей среды." + "<br>" +
       "- «Человек-Техника» - все профессии, связанные с техникой." + "<br>" +
       "- «Человек-Человек» - все профессии, связанные с обслуживанием людей." + "<br>" +
       "- «Человек-Знаковая система» - все профессии, связанные с подсчетами, цифровыми и буквенными знаками." + "<br>" +
       "- «Человек-Художественный образ» - все творческие специальности." + "<br>" ,
});
     
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've omitted your loop, which would be helpful.

However, a simple fix for your question would be to check if the email address exists before executing `sender_mail`:

```
if (adress.length) sender_mail(adress, name, chpri, chteh, chch, chzsis, chho);
```

Comment: Dont have error, but emails are not sent

Comment: @NuarFran Was it working before you added my code snippet?